# SVG / Inkscape / Masking

Tags: svg, inkscape

The following SVG show a symmetric difference of sets:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="3.2cm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 5 3.2" width="5.0cm">
<defs/>
<pattern height="0.14142135623730953" id="4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="0.14142135623730953">
    <path d="M -0.07071067811865477,0.07071067811865477 l 0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953 M -0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428 l 0.28284271247461906,-0.28284271247461906 M 0.07071067811865477,0.21213203435596428 l 0.14142135623730953,-0.14142135623730953" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:0.02"/>
</pattern>
<mask id="m1">
    <circle cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="white" r="1.5"/>
    <circle cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="black" r="1.5"/>
</mask>
<mask id="m2">
    <circle cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="white" r="1.5"/>
    <circle cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="black" r="1.5"/>
</mask>
<circle cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="url(#4)" mask="url(#m1)" r="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.04"/>
<circle cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="url(#4)" mask="url(#m2)" r="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.04"/>
<circle cx="2" cy="1.6" fill="none" r="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.04"/>
<circle cx="3" cy="1.6" fill="none" r="1.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.04"/>
</svg>
```

It works in the browser:
[image]
but with Inkscape I get in the Latex document following version:
[image]

> Is my SVG non correct (but the browser is error tolerant) or is there a limitation of Inkscape? (Forget about the texts)

Comment: Maybe look [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape) and report it if it's not already reported.

Comment: Your SVG validates at [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) so you should probably report it. Also, probably not suitable  for SO as it seems to be specific to Inkscape.

Comment: @RobertLongson 4996 open bugs :-)

Comment: Presumably fewer involving masks though.

Comment: probably lost time: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1810641

Comment: To work around this, avoid the use of masks. Try with a clip, I suspect that may work.

Comment: @Moini, thank you. that is exactly what I made, and it works. The resulting code is even shorter. But I'm still surprised that a 'professional' tool like Inkscape has such gaps

Comment: The pdf export has many bugs, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape?field.searchtext=pdf+export&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=